# How to get a pointerId from a MouseEvent for use with setPointerCapture?

Tags: javascript, html, pointer-events

How can I get the appropriate `pointerId` for a call to `setPointerCapture` if the source event is a MouseEvent, such as `mousedown`?

I'm looking for this because not all platforms support pointer events yet do support setPointerCapture (Safaria in particular).

`setPointerCapture` works with an undefined value, but I'd prefer to pass it an appropriate id.

---

I can't use `pointerdown` events since those are the unsupported events.  They contain a `pointerId`, but mouse events do not.

Comment: What version of Safari does support setPointerCapture but not PointerEvents? v13 certainly does support both.